# Android Face Detection dont finding faces

Tags: java, android, kotlin, face-detection

I want to find a face on an image from camera. But detector can't find faces. My app does photo and save it in file.

Below code which create file, start camera, and in `onActivityResult` in trying detect face and save file path to the room, its saving correctrly and showing in recycler view as expected, but face detector dont finding faces. how can i fix this?

```
    private fun takePhoto() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity?.packageManager!!) != null) {
        val photoFile: File
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            error { e }
        }
        val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity?.applicationContext!!, "com.nasibov.fakhri.neurelia.fileprovider", photoFile)
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PhotoFragment.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
    }
}

@Suppress("SimpleDateFormat")
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val fileName = "JPEG_$date"
    val filesDir = activity?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val image = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".jpg", filesDir)
    mCurrentImage = image
    return mCurrentImage
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImage.absolutePath)

        val frame = Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build()

        val detectedFaces = mFaceDetector.detect(frame)

        mViewModel.savePhoto(mCurrentImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola library to get cropped faces from bitmap image

Answer (score 0):

Android Face detection API tracks face in photos, videos using some landmarks like eyes, nose, ears, cheeks, and mouth.
Rather than detecting the individual features, the API detects the face at once and then if defined, detects the landmarks and classifications. Besides, the API can detect faces at various angles too.

https://www.journaldev.com/15629/android-face-detection

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK contains an API for Face Detection: [android.media.FaceDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face) class. This class detects faces on the image. To detect faces call `findFaces` method of `FaceDetector` class. findFaces method returns a number of detected faces and fills the `FaceDetector.Faces[]` array. Please note, that findFaces method supports only bitmaps in RGB_565 format at this time.

Each instance of the FaceDetector.Face class contains the following information:

- Confidence that it’s actually a face – a float value between 0 and 1.
- Distance between the eyes – in pixels.
- Position (x, y) of the mid-point between the eyes.
- Rotations (X, Y, Z).

Unfortunately, it doesn’t contain a framing rectangle that includes the detected face.

Here is sample source code for face detection. This sample code enables a custom View that shows a saved image from an SD Card and draws transparent red circles on the detected faces.

```
class Face_Detection_View extends View {
            private static final int MAX_FACES = 10;
            private static final String IMAGE_FN = "face.jpg";
            private Bitmap background_image;
            private FaceDetector.Face[] faces;
            private int face_count;

            // preallocate for onDraw(...)
            private PointF tmp_point = new PointF();
            private Paint tmp_paint = new Paint();

            public Face_Detection_View(Context context) {
                    super(context);

                    // Load an image from SD Card
                    updateImage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + IMAGE_FN);
            }

            public void updateImage(String image_fn) {
                    // Set internal configuration to RGB_565
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    background_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_fn, bitmap_options);
                    FaceDetector face_detector = new FaceDetector(
                                    background_image.getWidth(),                                    background_image.getHeight(),

                                    MAX_FACES);

                    faces = new FaceDetector.Face[MAX_FACES];
                    // The bitmap must be in 565 format (for now).
                    face_count = face_detector.findFaces(background_image, faces);
                    Log.d("Face_Detection", "Face Count: " + String.valueOf(face_count));
            }

            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(background_image, 0, 0, null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < face_count; i++) {
                            FaceDetector.Face face = faces[i];
                            tmp_paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                            tmp_paint.setAlpha(100);
                            face.getMidPoint(tmp_point);
                            canvas.drawCircle(tmp_point.x, tmp_point.y, face.eyesDistance(),
                                            tmp_paint);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but i using `com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector`, i think smthing wrong with my bitmap or frame, but i dont understand what exactly, may be its something like color space or alfa chanel